# How to classify arrays using svm?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning

I want to make a model which can differentiate between general functions eg. If a given set of points fall on a line or a parabola etc. 
I am not able to train a svc directly on arrays as it expects an array of 2d shape
Any suggestions?
Note: eventually i want to build it into classifying into periodic functions given a set of data points

Answer (score 0):

Okay so your input is an array of points, each point has coordinates (x,y) and your label is the type of function.

In math, this task is called interpolation and this is where you get a set of points and you return the function that should be returned.

What you are describing seems more like non-linear regression (curve fitting) than it is about classification, you'll have too many classes to cover and it doesn't really make sense to do that anyway.

Here is a tutorial in python about non-linear regression that would be more useful. https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html

Comment: But i dont want to differentiate between 2x+1 and 3x+2

Comment: My actual problem is classifying light curves from stars to check if they are variables or not....so only a type of curve is specified not the actual function

Comment: Then you can take the output function from the curve fitting task and just classify it with simple if statements based on the order of the function and the bias. If order is one, it is a line, x square a parabola and so on. As I mentioned in my answer, and why I think you have been downvoted, your task doesn't work as a simple classification problem, it is a lot more than that. You don't need ML to just classify the way you are describing, you can literally just compute the slope between random different points and approximate your label without training anything.